# Validate nested properties with fluent validation request sent from swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to send the `[HttpPost]` using swagger, I have placed validation properties in the child properties using the fluent validation.

But the fluent validation is ignoring the validation rules.

The Basic structure of my class looks as:

```cs
public class ChargeCreateRequestModel
{
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public IList<TaxRequestModel> Taxes { get; set; }

}

public class TaxRequestModel
{
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Plus4 { get; set; }
}
```

The validation rules set for the nested class properties:

```cs
public class TaxValidator : AbstractValidator<TaxRequestModel>
{
    public TaxValidator()
    {

        RuleFor(x => x.Zip)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Must(IsAllDigits)
            .Length(5);
    }

    private bool IsAllDigits(string arg)
    {
        return int.TryParse(arg, out _);
    }
}
```

The controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse<string>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateCharge([FromBody] ChargeCreateRequestModel requestModel)
{
    await _chargeService.CreateChargeAsync(requestModel);
    return Ok(new ApiResponse<string>($"List of charge"));
}
```

If the nested property is null or with any string, the validation is always successful. The validation are just ignored.

What approach should i use to make the validation works for the nested properties with fluent validation while posting from swagger?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement validator for ChargeCreateRequestModel

Comment: What should I include on that?

Comment: Because I have already implement that for other fields, which I have not post here in the question.